# How to load JSON objects into a select object

Tags: javascript, json, html-select

I'm trying to load objects from a JSON file into a select tag in my HTML file. I need the "author" property from each object to become a separate option in my select tag.

My code in the HTML is simple (and I'm not allowed to modify it as per my teacher's instructions)

```
<label for="filterAuthor">Author:</label>
<select id="filterAuthor"><option value="">All Authors</option></select>
```

Properties in my JSON file look like this:

```
{
    "bookshelf":
    [
        {
            "title":"Ulysses",
            "author":"James Joyce",
            "year":1922,
            "link":"https://smile.amazon.com/Ulysses-Wordsworth-Classics-James-Joyce/dp/1840226358/"
        }, }
```

The script is where my problem is. We haven't been taught anything about jquery (which is the methods including $ symbols, I believe?), so our teacher wants us to find a way to do this without using it. How do I get the options from my JSON file to load in the script?

```
<script>
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4) {
            var response = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
            var x = document.getElementById("filterAuthor");
            for(var i = 0; i < response.bookshelf.length; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = response.bookshelf[i].author;
                x.add(option);
                }
            }
        }

        ajax.open("GET","products.json");

        ajax.send();
    </script>
```

I tried looking for answers on the internet, and this is the closest to what I thought would work that I got. It obviously doesn't work though. Can someone help me?

Comment: _"It obviously doesn't work though"_ ok what about it doesn't work? Are you getting errors on the console? Are you getting invalid `<option>` elements? Have you tried using the debugger and stepping through the call?

Comment: Pretty sure var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); is not what you are looking for since your data is Json not XML.  Where is the json stored or how are you supposed to get it?  Is it a static file within your current project or is it available from an API?

Comment: ruby_newbie, your statement is incorrect, XMLHttpRequest is the right way to go. The name is just misleading. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: take a look here to see an example on how to load JSON with Ajax, without jQuery: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#json

Comment: Patrick, I am getting errors on the console.  XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/aelita/Desktop/Winter%20Term%202017/CIS197CSP/Week%208/Homework/Week%208%20Project%20Files/products.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
(anonymous) @ index.html:120
index.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ajax.onreadystatechange (index.html:108)
    at index.html:120

Comment: ruby_newbie , This is the code my teacher used in all the examples in class and we're supposed to be able to do the homework with what we learned in class and the notes she gives us.

Comment: That error tells you what is wrong __Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource__, meaning browsers will not let you load files from the local filesystem (ie file:///). It is a security issue, if it was allowed any website could read any file on your hard drive